# ggplot not finding object in aes

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have following dataframe and function:

```
structure(list(vnum1 = c(-0.853002701467605, -2.41044831451325, 
                          1.22391941685926, 0.539011835935724, 
                         -1.33616761309235, -1.33762097068431, 
                          0.0391687995434752, -0.0396899713936502, 
                          -1.34004495967791, 0.731212395958092), 

                vnum2 = c(-0.0140296461607895, 0.649714762844125, 
                          -0.202655014660386, 1.90785563726907, 
                           0.240191747220876, 0.0395243104031934, 
                           -2.1689146110194, -0.198126356757339, 
                           1.89172814288286, -0.484592561521101), 
             vint1 = c(7L, 4L, 7L, 3L, 10L, 10L, 7L, 8L, 2L, 3L), 
             vint2 = c(2L, 8L, 2L, 7L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 8L, 4L, 6L), 
             vfac1 = structure(c(3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L),
            .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4"), class = "factor"), 
             vfac2 = structure(c(3L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L), 
            .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4"), class = "factor"), 
             vch1 = structure(c(5L,  1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 5L), 
            .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), class = "factor"), 
             vbin1 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L), 
            .Label = c("a", "b"), class = "factor")), 
            .Names = c("vnum1", "vnum2", "vint1", "vint2", "vfac1", "vfac2", "vch1", "vbin1"), 
            row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
> 

grfour1 <- function(gdf, first, second, third, fourth){
    ggplot(gdf, aes(first, second)) + 
        geom_point(position = position_jitter(width = 0.2, height = 0)) + 
        facet_grid(third~fourth) 
}
```

On running the command, I get this error:

```
> grfour1(rndf, vint1, vint2,vch1,vint2)
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'second' not found
>
```

Where is the error? Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues here. First, `ggplot` parses column names into the `aes` without the quotes, thus when you do `aes(first, second)`, `ggplot2` actually looks for columns named `"first"` and `"second"` rather the variables that contains the names you parsed.
Second problem is that R doesn't know whats `vints`, he thinks it's some object in the global enviroment, thus, you need to tell it that this is a character using `"vint1"`

My solution will be

```
grfour1 <- function(gdf, first, second, third, fourth){
    gdf <- gdf[c(first, second, third, fourth)]
    names(gdf) <- c("first", "second", "third", "fourth") 
    ggplot(gdf, aes(first, second)) + 
      geom_point(position = position_jitter(width = 0.2, height = 0)) + 
      facet_grid(third ~ fourth) 
  }
library(ggplot2)
grfour1(rndf, "vint1", "vint2", "vch1", "vint2")
```

Comment: I tried but I am getting following error:> grfour1(ndf,"vnum1","vnum2", "vch1", "vbin1")
Error: Casting formula contains variables not found in molten data: vch1, vbin1

Comment: @rnso, isn't your data called `rndf`? cause you parsed `ndf` instead... Anyway, this code works without doubt, I've tested it several times on your data

Comment: I must not have attached it earlier (rndf and ndf are same). It is working very well. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

Your column names are only visible to the `ggplot` function because it uses the data as its environment. They are not visible to R in your global environment. To fix the problem your function definition should be:

```
grfour1 <- function(gdf, first, second, third, fourth){
    ggplot(gdf, aes_string(first, second)) + 
      geom_point(position = position_jitter(width = 0.2, height = 0)) + 
      facet_grid(paste(third, "~", fourth)) 
}
```

In this case `first` to `fourth` should be `character` variables:

```
grfour1(rndf, "vint1", "vint2", "vch1", "vint2")
```

Comment: I am getting: > grfour1_ilir(rndf, "vint1", "vint2", "vch1", "vint2")
Error: Casting formula contains variables not found in molten data: vch1, vint2

Answer (score 0):

```
grfour1 <- function(gdf, first, second, third, fourth){
  ggplot(gdf, aes_string(deparse(substitute(first)), deparse(substitute(second)))) + 
    geom_point(position = position_jitter(width = 0.2, height = 0)) +
    facet_grid(deparse(substitute(third~fourth))) 
}
```

should work with `grfour1(rndf, vint1, vint2,vch1,vint2)`, if you called e.g. `attach(rndf)` before. Explanation see @ilir & @DavidArenburg.

Comment: I am getting: > grfour1_luke(rndf, "vint1", "vint2", "vch1", "vint2")
Error: Casting formula contains variables not found in molten data: "vch1", "vint2"
> grfour1_luke(rndf, vint1, vint2, vch1, vint2)
Error: Casting formula contains variables not found in molten data: vch1, vint2; > grfour1_luke(rndf, vint1, vint2, vch1, vint2)
Error: Casting formula contains variables not found in molten data: vch1, vint2
>